# Secure Pages redirection result in '302 Found' status

Tags: redirect, drupal-7

In [Secure Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages) module, https to http and vise versa redirection are result into '302 found' status. 
Can we have some kind of 'hook_alter' to modify it. In my project requirement its needs to redirect with '301 Moved Permanently' status. If there are other ways to handle it please let me know.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the patch, hope they will include in upcoming release with configuration setting.

Ref : https://www.drupal.org/node/506522